# Quick Sort in C

Tags: c, sorting, reinventing-the-wheel

I'd like to know if there's any issues with this implementation of `qsort_r` (which is not available in all implementations, so I'm trying to provide one that allows to compare values in a dynamic environment) and whether it could be improved upon.

```
typedef int32_t compare_fn(void *data, const void *val1, const void *val2);

void memswap(void *mem1, void *mem2, size_t size)
{
    uint8_t buffer[size];

    memcpy(buffer, mem1, size);
    memcpy(mem1, mem2, size);
    memcpy(mem2, buffer, size);
}

void qsort_r(void *mem_low, void *mem_hi, size_t size, compare_fn compare, void *data)
{
    if (mem_low >= mem_hi || mem_hi < mem_low)
    {
        return;
    }

    uint8_t *mem_i = mem_low;
    uint8_t *mem_j = mem_low;

    while (mem_j < mem_hi)
    {
        if (compare(data, mem_j, mem_hi) < 0)
        {
            memswap(mem_i, mem_j, size);
            mem_i += size;
        }

        mem_j += size;
    }

    memswap(mem_i, mem_hi, size);

    qsort_r(mem_low, mem_i - size, size, compare, data);
    qsort_r(mem_i + size, mem_hi, size, compare, data);
}
```

Comment: Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I have rolled back Rev 4 → 2

Answer (score 6):

1. Pointer-arithmetic on `void*` is an error in standard c. Yes, gcc/clang have an extension assuming that `sizeof(void) == 1`. Ramp up your warning-level and specify the standard.
2. That's an interesting method to swap two blocks of memory.

   Using a variable length array invites undefined behavior though, as the amount of stack requested is pretty much unbounded.

   Anyway, it would probably be a good idea to implement it directly, without such a buffer.

   ```
   void memswap(void* a, void* b, size_t n) {
       unsigned char *c = a, *d = b;
       while (n--) {
           unsigned char x = *c;
           *c++ = *d;
           *d++ = x;
       }
   }
   ```
3. I somewhat expected all the elements to be between `mem_low` and `mem_hi`. You seem to have an element at `mem_hi`.
   At least if you sort a null terminated string, it just sorts the terminator too.

Did you try to run your code? See it break a basic test-case [live on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cf415d6ca237932).

Comment: I had tried it on an integer array of 10k elements, but it hid a nasty bug. My pivot cannot be `mem_hi`, it must be `mem_hi - size`. This change will solve (1). As for (2), it is very interesting, would there be a performance difference? I'll update the code with the changes.

Answer (score 5):

`if (mem_low >= mem_hi || mem_hi < mem_low)`

The second part of that if is completely redundant.